How can I add storybook to an existing repo in a Nx package based configuration?
It seems you can't manually add storybook to an existing Angular project once it's inside an Nx monorepo without following the integrated path.
I've setup an Nx monorepo using the standalone package configuration, there are several angular libraries which have been generated using the angular cli.
I've got to the point where I want to add Storybook to a library and tried to use the standard Storybook approach by calling:
 npx storybook@latest init

but this results in the following error:
 SB_CLI_INIT_0001 (NxProjectDetectedError): We have detected Nx in your project. Nx has its own Storybook initializer, so please use it instead.
Run "nx g @nx/storybook:configuration" to add Storybook to your project.

The problem is I don't want to follow the integrated route, I would like to keep things separate. What is the best approach of adding storybook in this scenario?
Thanks, any help is appreciated.

https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/overview-angular. This may help you .
